# constexpr function with extern static table

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, one-definition-rule

There are similar questions about, but none I've found that directly answer this question.

I want to implement a constexpr function like this:

```
constexpr int Foo(int x) {
  static const int table[128] = { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, ..., 99 };
  return (0 <= x && x < 128) ? table[x] : 42;
}
```

I'm wary of making the table function-static as shown because the compiler might add expensive checks to make initialization of the table thread safe (slowing each call), and those checks might make the optimizer less likely to inline this otherwise trivial function.

So thought I'd move the table to namespace static, defining it in one .cpp file, while the function itself remains defined in a header so that it can be inlined.

```
constexpr int Foo(int x) {
  extern constexpr int table[];
  return (0 <= x && x < 128) ? table[x] : 42;
}
```

The compiler complains that I can't declare `table` inside a constexpr function.  So then I tried:

```
extern constexpr int table[];
constexpr int Foo(int x) {
  return (0 <= x && x < 128) ? table[x] : 42;
}
```

That's not allowed because you can't just declare something constexpr, you have to define it.  But if I define the table in a header file, I'll violate the one-definition rule, right?

```
constexpr int table[128] = { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, ..., 99 };
constexpr int Foo(int x) {
  return (0 <= x && x < 128) ? table[x] : 42;
}
```

I know Foo doesn't violate ODR, because constexpr implies inline for function definitions.  The compiler accepts this and seems to do the right thing, but I know compilers aren't required to issue a diagnostic for ODR violations.

Q1:  In this last iteration, is `table` an ODR violation?

Q2:  If not, is there a way to prevent `table` from being visible to every translation unit that includes this header?

Comment: "*I'm wary of making the table function-static as shown because ...*" This is simply not a realistic concern with `int`s due to [constant initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization).

Comment: @ildjarn:  Fair enough, but there are additional motivations for the question.   My compiler (VC++2015) won't let me declare the table as function static inside a constexpr function, which I think requires C++14 compliance.

Comment: Fortunately, VC++2017 will at least. :-]

Comment: Regarding Q1, `constexpr` implies `const` implies `static`, so yes, it's an ODR violation. In C++17 it can be marked `inline` to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Q1 (if you define `table` `static`?) but, for Q2, I propose `Foo()` as a `friend` function for a class where `table` is a `private` `static constexpr` member.

By example

```
#include <iostream>

class wrapTable
 {
   private:
      static constexpr int table[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19 };
      static constexpr int size { sizeof(table)/sizeof(table[0]) };

      friend constexpr int foo (int);
 };

constexpr int wrapTable::table[];

constexpr int foo (int x)
 { return (0 <= x && x < wrapTable::size) ? wrapTable::table[x] : 42; }

int main()
 {
   std::cout << "foo(3): " << foo(3) << std::endl; // print 7
   std::cout << "foo(9): " << foo(9) << std::endl; // print 42

   // compilation error: 'table' is a private member of 'wrapTable'
   // std::cout << "table(3): " << wrapTable::table[3] << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Interesting idea.  My compiler is not accepting the `constexpr int wrapTable::table[];` line.  Even if it had worked, it still pollutes each consumer's namespace, just with `wrapTable` instead of `table`.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy - wich compiler are you using?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy - that is more new than my g++ 4.9.2 or my clang++ 3.5.0... It's wrong my code? Which message error show your VC++?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy : Change `static constexpr int table[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19 };` to `static constexpr int table[8] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19 };` and it should compile fine in VC++ 2015.